# How to reply to a message(existing conversation) in channel using teams bot

Tags: bots, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

Suppose I have messageId of a Post in a teams channel. Is there a way to send reply to that post through BOT SDK api.

**What I want to achieve --**

Suppose there is a channel containing 40 posts.
On calling the bot anywhere in the channel, send proactive replies to all these posts. The replies that I have to send are mapped with an api, which I can directly fetch.

I want through https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/bot-initiate-thread-in-channel/python/app.py

Here a new conversation is being created before sending the reply.

Comment: SO is for programming questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this using [Proactive Messaging](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python/16.proactive-messages). We can store conversation_references when mentioning the bot, and map them to activity id. (Here it was mapped to userId)